# Angular Material Toolbar Transparent

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to remove the dark background from my material toolbar.
I'm able through class assignments in the html template like color="primary" or through class="toolbar" and corresponding css references to change the color of the bar to my liking but whenever I choose transparent it seems that the underlying dark color is from the material dark color scheme and I didnt find a way to remove it.

My goal is to have the linear gradient over the entire background including the navigation bar.

Anyone an idea? Would appreciate the help. (Using Angular Material with Dark Theme and Custom Color Palette)

My code:

app.component.html

```
<div class="gradient">
  <app-navbar> </app-navbar>
  <router-outlet> </router-outlet>
</div>
```

app.component.scss

```
.gradient {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right bottom,
    #292e42,
    #543a61,
    #8e3d6a,
    #c34459,
    #e06332
  );
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

mat-tabs css

```
.mat-toolbar.mat-primary {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't `mat-toolbar` transparent by default?

Comment: We might need to see more of your CSS, what you want to do is certainly possible: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8bdobg?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftoolbar-basic-example.css,src%2Fapp%2Ftoolbar-basic-example.html,src%2Fstyles.scss

Comment: Thank you robbie, I think your stackblitz might be able to help me out already. Atleast that looks pretty neat to me. I'll have to wait for the weekend though until I have some free time to work on that project again and then I will update on my progress and in case I fail add additional infos about my CSS :)